# How can I darken an image using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that spans the entire screen:

```
<div>
  <img className="background-image" src={url} /> 

  <h1>{name}</h1>
  ... 

</div>


 .background-image {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
 }
```

Now, I'd like to darken the whole image. How can I do this? I tried adding a div next to the image with a black background and full width and height, but that messes up everything. All I'm trying to do is darken the image, so that the text on the page can be read easily.

Comment: use the css property `filter: brightness(0.5);` for the image. Change the 0.5 to darker or lighter depending on what you want

Comment: Thanks that works.  Having another issue--some of the text elements (like the h1) are not visible because of the image. I tried playing with the z-index, but that doesn't do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: `className`? o_O

Comment: @Capsule I think OP's using react

Comment: Then it's missing a tag :-) (I actually removed the javascript one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `filter` property will do it, but that isn't widely supported. I would use a pseudo element positioned absolutely over the image with an `rgba()` background, or a solid background combined with `opacity`.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: black;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: .5;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png"></div>
```

Comment: another way to do it is with background-blend-mode... again not supported everywhere. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-blend-mode.asp

Comment: The thing is I want my image to span the entire screen. This method make the image span only across the div's width and height.

Comment: @Prabhu I don't see how that's relevant. The div wraps the image and conforms to the image's size - not the other way around. That's what `inline-block` does. You could also make the div `block` (or just remove the `display` property) and make the image `width: 100%`.

Comment: @Prabhu here's an example with a full width image https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/NjpPOV

Comment: Good answer but I'd rather use `:before` and set the opacity on the image. Why? Because in this case the image is still in front and you still get the potential `title` on it, or the correct contextual menu when right clicked.

Comment: @Capsule nice, hadn't considered that before. I like it. Updated.

Comment: I'd use photoshop. hahaha. If I had to use CSS - this would be the answer!

Comment: @sheriffderek sup bae?? for real. Or a PHP endpoint that takes 2 query strings - the image path and brightness level, then uses GD or ImageMagick or something to return the modified image. It's like a photoshop API.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about IE use `filter: brightness()`, see [can i use filters](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

div {
  position: relative
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  filter: brightness(.7)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="background-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" />
</div>
```

otherwise for cross browser you can use pseudo element `::after` with background `rgba`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

div {
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  content: "";
}

img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="background-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/1000/sports" />
</div>
```

**EDIT** - OP's comment

> The thing is I want my image to span the entire screen. This method
>   make the image span only across the div's width and height

So use a background image instead of a image.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports) no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
  margin: 0;
  height:100vh
}

body::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass a variable image to css's background property? I.e. I don't know what the image url is until runtime. Using reactjs.

Comment: yes if you use something like this  `<body style="background:url(variable)">`

Answer (score 1):

create an overly like that

like that

```
 .overly{
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0; 
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```

and put it inside your div alongside with your image or just give your container this class 
You can use `z-index` in case of layers positioning

Answer (score 0):

Yu can also use linear gradients on images. you can use generators online for fall backs

```css
div{
    background-image: url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B3000000,endColorstr=#B3000000);
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
    url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 200px;
    width: 30%;
    }
    div+div{
background-image: url(https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/fruits.png);
    }
```

```html
Darkened
<div></div>
Original
<div></div>
```